# iOS:How to make a horizontal paging UIScrollView with Auto Animation Of Images For Home Page

Tags: objective-c

I have a Home Screen Where Multiple image is animated in horizontal way,so how can i achieve that with page controller  anyone

Thx In Advc. (^_^)

Answer (score 2):

This is a PageViewController. 
Take a look at this tutorial: 
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: Nice one- looks amazing

Comment: Oh ok.. 
I've changed my answer then